# Three variables inequality with third power exponents

Tags: inequality

With $a,b,c >0$ prove $$(a^3+b^3+c^3)\left( \frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{c^3} \right)\ge \frac{3}{2} \sum_{\text{cyclic}} \frac{b+c}{a}$$

Comment: What have you attempted ?

Comment: What does $\sum \frac{b+c}{a}$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this sum is given by $$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

By $AM\ge GM$,

\begin{align*}
  1+\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac{b^3}{c^3} & \ge \frac{3a}{c} \\
  1+\frac{b^3}{c^3}+\frac{c^3}{a^3} & \ge \frac{3b}{a} \\
  1+\frac{c^3}{a^3}+\frac{a^3}{b^3} & \ge \frac{3c}{b} \\
  1+\frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{a^3}{c^3} & \ge \frac{3b}{c} \\
  1+\frac{a^3}{c^3}+\frac{c^3}{b^3} & \ge \frac{3a}{b} \\
  1+\frac{c^3}{b^3}+\frac{b^3}{a^3} & \ge \frac{3c}{a} \\
  (a^3+b^3+c^3) \left( \frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{1}{c^3} \right) &=
  3+\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac{b^3}{c^3}+\frac{c^3}{a^3}+
    \frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{c^3}{b^3}+\frac{a^3}{c^3} \\
  & \ge \frac{3}{2} 
    \left(
      \frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{a}
    \right) \\
  &= \frac{3}{2}
     \left(
       \frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}
     \right)
\end{align*}